# jQuery toggle function doesn't work on first click

Tags: jquery, toggle

i want to create a simple toggle function which toggles a div show() or hide() with a cookie to remember in which state the div is. So far so good. Well, it works kind of. When i toggle the div hide() it hides, but when i reload the page an want to toggle the div show() i have to click the button twice ! I've read the anwers here in but they didn't help. Also i've tried to make it with a click function but that doesn't work at all.

Here ist the code:

```
  jQuery().ready(function () {

        var footeroff = jQuery.cookie('footeroff'); 
        var toggle_footer = jQuery(".toggle_footer_switch");

        if (footeroff == "off") {
        jQuery("div#footer").hide();
        jQuery("div#wkfooter_switch").hide();
        toggle_footer.html("<img src='../images/other/zuklappen.png' border='0'>");
        };

        if (footeroff == "on") {
        jQuery("div#footer").show();
        jQuery("div#wkfooter_switch").show();
        toggle_footer.html("<img src='../images/other/aufklappen.png' border='0'>");
        };

        var footer_switch = jQuery("div#footer");
        var toggle_footer = jQuery(".toggle_footer_switch");
        var toggle_switch_div = jQuery("div#toggle_switch_div");

        jQuery("a.toggle_footer_switch").toggle(
            function () {
                toggle_footer.html("<img src='../images/other/zuklappen.png' border='0'>");
                jQuery("div#footer").fadeOut("slow");
                jQuery("div#wkfooter_switch").hide();
                jQuery.cookie("footeroff" , "off");
            },
            function () {
                toggle_footer.html("<img src='../images/other/aufklappen.png' border='0'>");
                jQuery("div#footer").fadeIn("slow");
                jQuery("div#wkfooter_switch").show();
                jQuery.cookie("footeroff" , "on");
            }   
        );


    });
```

And there is the code with a click function:

```
      jQuery().ready(function () {

        var footeroff = jQuery.cookie('footeroff'); 
        var toggle_footer = jQuery(".toggle_footer_switch");

        if (footeroff == "off") {
        jQuery("div#footer").hide();
        jQuery("div#wkfooter_switch").hide();
        toggle_footer.html("<img src='../images/other/zuklappen.png' border='0'>");
        };

        if (footeroff == "on") {
        jQuery("div#footer").show();
        jQuery("div#wkfooter_switch").show();
        toggle_footer.html("<img src='../images/other/aufklappen.png' border='0'>");
        };

        var footer_switch = jQuery("div#footer");
        var toggle_footer = jQuery(".toggle_footer_switch");
        var toggle_switch_div = jQuery("div#toggle_switch_div");


        jQuery("a.toggle_footer_switch").click(function() {

            if (footer_switch.is(":visible")) {
                toggle_footer.html("<img src='../images/other/zuklappen.png' border='0'>");
                jQuery("div#footer").hide();
                jQuery("div#wkfooter_switch").hide();
                jQuery.cookie("footeroff" , "off");
            }
            else if (footer_switch.is(":hidden")) {
                toggle_footer.html("<img src='../images/other/aufklappen.png' border='0'>");
                jQuery("div#footer").show();
                jQuery("div#wkfooter_switch").show();
                jQuery.cookie("footeroff" , "on");
            }

        });


    });
```

Thank you very much!

Best regards

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As your code using `click` looks identical to the code using `toggle`, it's probably best to use that space in the question to post your HTML instead.  That will enable people to quickly get a demo working in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) in order to help solve your problem.  That is, unless you want to set up a demo there yourself! :)

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work?

```
jQuery().ready(function () {

    var footeroff = jQuery.cookie('footeroff'); 
    var toggle_footer = jQuery(".toggle_footer_switch");

    toggle_footer.toggle(
        function () {
            toggle_footer.html("<img src='../images/other/zuklappen.png' border='0'>");
            jQuery("div#footer").fadeOut("slow");
            jQuery("div#wkfooter_switch").hide();
            jQuery.cookie("footeroff" , "off");
        },
        function () {
            toggle_footer.html("<img src='../images/other/aufklappen.png' border='0'>");
            jQuery("div#footer").fadeIn("slow");
            jQuery("div#wkfooter_switch").show();
            jQuery.cookie("footeroff" , "on");
        }   
    );
    // since the page starts off with the div shown, so let's hide it.
    // note that this will do the slow fade - you may want to check for this inside the toggle function and just do an instant hide() instead
    if (footeroff == "off") {
        toggle_footer.toggle();
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi Gregl, that now hides the .toogle_footer. :D I dont know why..but any ..no, sorry, still needs a double click. :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but just for people that are looking for a quick fix, this worked for me:

a. in the PHP/HTML file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/.../jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#pClick").click(function(){          
            $("#pText").toggle();
            $("#pText").text("...");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

b. in the CSS file:

```
#pText {display: none;}
```

It now works even on the first click. It's a simple, quick answer that I hope will be useful to somebody.